# How to make a vector (saved as a string) a vector back again?

Tags: r

I saved polygon coordinates to the database and this is how it's saved to a table:

```
c(22.841941, 23.413109, 21.831413, 22.841941, 50.134664, 49.453843, 49.353756, 50.134664)
```

Now, I need to read it to R and make it polygon again but the issue is that when I read coordinates from database then they are of type `character` (with quotation marks):

```
"c(22.841941, 23.413109, 21.831413, 22.841941, 50.134664, 49.453843, 49.353756, 50.134664)"
```

I wanted to make it vector again `c(22.841941, 23.413109,...)` - remove somehow the quotations marks. I tried some string operations e.g.:

```
text <- "c(22.841941, 23.413109, 21.831413, 22.841941, 50.134664, 49.453843, 49.353756, 50.134664)" 
stringr::str_replace(text, "\""," ")
```

or:

```
gsub('"',"",text)
```

but it doesn't remove quotation marks. And sure, I also tried to make it a list by `list(text)` or numeric `as.numeric(text)` but all of these operations fail. How can I make this string-vector a vector (or matrix/list, whatever) again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `eval/parse`

```
text1 <- eval(parse(text = text))
str(text1)
#num [1:8] 22.8 23.4 21.8 22.8 50.1 ...
```

---

Instead of saving it as a string, it may be better to use `dput` and save it in a `.R` file, then it can be reproduced easily

```
dput(head(iris))
```